# Performance on a screen with 26 forms

Tags: powerapps

I have 26 forms on a single screen (Tela Geral) because of issues I was having ([here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Store-scroll-state/m-p/1693157#M430890)). I use a gallery to call a specific form by title.

[image]

The problem is that when I need to enter the screen (Tela Geral) where the 26 forms are, there is a big slowdown.

I would not like to go back to working with the previous way I used, which was 26 screens, one for each form (because of the scroll problem mentioned above), but it ended up causing this unexpected slowness.

We've talked a bit in the [Microsoft community about this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Performance-on-a-screen-with-26-forms/m-p/1697456#M432104), but if there are any new ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was preferable before the General Screen to have a screen with 26 buttons. Sorted out.